# How do I set Haskell benchmarking up with Stack's package.yaml?

Tags: haskell

I keep seeing directions to set benchmarking up in my project's foo.cabal file, but surely there is a way to set it up in package.yaml?

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`package.yaml` is a configuration processed by the tool **hpack**, which stack just calls. From [the doc of hpack](https://github.com/sol/hpack#quick-reference) we can see that there is a `benchmarks` field, that works mostly like `tests`.

Comment: Ah. So there *was* something obvious I was missing. Thank you :)